# quilljs how to have a font picker with a button with icon instead of a select that shows the font name

Tags: javascript, picker, quill

This question is about quilljs and applying the color picker behaviour to the font select...

[image]
this example brings a select with the font name..... but I prefer a picker like for the colors...

```
var toolbarOptions = [
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
  ...
  [{ 'font': [] }],
];
quill = new Quill('#editor', { modules:{toolbar:toolbarOptions}, theme:'snow'});
```

OR

```
<div id="tools" >
  <button class="ql-underline" ></button>
  <button class="ql-strike" ></button>
  <select class="ql-font" >'..<options>..'</select>
  <select class="ql-color" >'..<options>..'</select>
</div>
<script>quill = new Quill('#editor', { modules:{toolbar:"#tools"}, theme:'snow'});</script>
```

Where in the code can I look ? or what option can I apply ?

Answer (score 0):

here I changed .css and .js

...

snow.css

```
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font {display: inline-block;margin: unset;position: relative;top: 4px;}
.ql-snow .ql-picker-label::before {  display: inline-block;  overflow: hidden;  color: white;  font-size: 0px;}
.ql-snow .ql-picker-label::before {  width: 42px;  height: 42px;}
.ql-snow .ql-picker:not(.ql-color-picker):not(.ql-icon-picker) svg {  position: absolute;  right: 0;  top: 2px;  width: 89%;  left: 2px;  bottom: 0;}
```

.js

```
/***/ }),
/* 107 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
module.exports = "<svg fill='#000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  viewBox='0 0 48 48' ><path d='M 24.572266 6.9667969 A 2.50025 2.50025 0 0 0 24.105469 7 L 22.255859 7 C 17.317722 7 13.95134 8.7120695 11.931641 10.503906 C 9.9119413 12.295743 9.1289063 14.292969 9.1289062 14.292969 A 2.0002213 2.0002213 0 1 0 12.871094 15.707031 C 12.871094 15.707031 13.224136 14.704257 14.585938 13.496094 C 15.863666 12.362518 17.952824 11.173612 21.546875 11.029297 C 20.492354 15.315964 19.591948 18.906058 18.798828 22 L 18 22 A 2.0002 2.0002 0 0 0 17.773438 25.988281 C 16.641524 30.213927 15.758259 33.080369 14.966797 34.908203 C 14.175212 36.736321 13.580917 37.35668 13.162109 37.613281 C 12.743302 37.869882 12.097546 38 10.648438 38 C 8.895338 38 6.3652344 37.154297 6.3652344 37.154297 A 2.50025 2.50025 0 1 0 4.6347656 41.845703 C 4.6347656 41.845703 7.527536 43 10.648438 43 C 12.352329 43 14.121386 42.890352 15.775391 41.876953 C 17.429395 40.863554 18.564021 39.182413 19.554688 36.894531 C 20.627075 34.417917 21.679509 30.892333 22.960938 26 L 32 26 A 2.0002 2.0002 0 1 0 32 22 L 23.980469 22 C 24.774709 18.841382 25.653771 15.283749 26.705078 11 L 41 11 A 2.0002 2.0002 0 1 0 41 7 L 24.898438 7 A 2.50025 2.50025 0 0 0 24.572266 6.9667969 z'/></svg>";
/***/ }
```